# Difference(s): android:src and tools:src?

Tags: android

> **Difference(s): `android:src` and `tools:src`?**

If any, when is it considered proper to use `tools:src` over `android:src`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using `android:src` in xml during runtime this will show up on the app, whereas if you use `tools:src` in xml it will show only on the preview of Android studio and not on the runtime of the app.

Answer (score 3):

If you start to use support library ([`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc-in-androids-layout-xml/40624625#40624625)), change `tools:src` to `tools:srcCompat`