# tools:src is not working with support library

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, android-support-library

I'm using `tools:src` for `ImageView` to show sample vector image in Android Studio (v3.4.2) design preview (check this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753804/differences-androidsrc-and-toolssrc))

It worked well, but if I start use support library ([`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc-in-androids-layout-xml/40624625#40624625)), `tools:src` stop working - no preview in design tool.

How can I enable design preview of vector graphics with support library enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer by myself. Change `tools:src` to `tools:srcCompat`